# Gallbladder/Ulcer Pain

Tags: ulcers, gallbladder

Is it possible that duodenal ulcer (diagnosed with an endoscopy) could trigger gallbladder dyskinesia (diagnosed with a HIDA scan).

Comment: Theoretically, there could be a connection, because you've said there is "only" dyskinesia, but no other organic problem, like stones, right? One painful condition (ulcer) could trigger other painful condition (dyskinesia). I strongly recommend you to try your best to treat the ulcers and prevent their further development. Ask your doctor what could be risk factors for ulcers in your case (stress, certain medications, H. pylori...).

Comment: @Jennifer, I edited your question to make it less like asking for a medical advice and to prevent its closure. You can accept or refuse this edit.

Answer (score 2):

Both a duodenal ulcer and gallbladder dyskinesia can result from stress.

- [Duodenal ulcer and stress](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3613748/)
- [Biliary dyskinesia and stress](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21919240)

Duodenal ulcer can, rarely, affect the opening of the common bile duct (sphincter of Oddi) into the duodenum and cause "sphincter of Oddi dysfunction" ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2074063)), which is one type of "biliary dyskinesia."

*NOTE: It is important to obtain a written medical diagnosis to know which exact type of gallbladder or biliary dyskinesia one has, because different types have different causes and treatments.*

---

Since the treatment for duodenal ulcer is better known and, in general, more succesful than for dyskinesia, it seems logical that one should try to treat the ulcer first.